# How do pass the id of a form onKeyUp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onkeyup

There's plenty of questions on how to get the value onKeyUp, but I want to pass the id of the form onKeyUp as well..  I tried something like this, but it's telling me getId is not defined.

```
function getId(x){
$('.not').append(x);
}

var word = 'HELP';

$('.why').html("<form class='questions'><input type='text' id='"+word+"' 
name='"+word+"' onkeyup='getId("+word+")'></form> ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evs3A/

Also is putting something like `"+variable+"` bad practice, because I'm using it quite a lot ;)?  Thank u.

Comment: I ended up putting `onkeyup=getId(this.id)` in the form and that seems to work fine on my local machine, but doesn't work on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/evs3A/2/ for some reason.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to hook up the event and avoid the problem altogether. Try this:

```
var word = 'HELP';
$('.why').html("<form class='questions'><input type='text' id='" + word + "' 
name='" + word + "'></form> ");

$('.questions input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $('.not').append(this.id);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv3sG/)

Answer (score 1):

you can change it into this:

```
$('.why').html("<form class='questions'><input type='text' id='"+word+"' 
name='"+word+"'></form> ");
```

and in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var word = 'HELP';
    $(document).on('keyup', '#' + word, function(){
        $('.not').append(word); //or $(this).attr('id'); if the id is the argument that you want to pass
    });
});
```

if you want to change a variable to pass you can use data value like this:

```
<input type='text' id='"+word+"' name='"+word+"' data-something="new_value">
```

and take it in this mode:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#' + word, function(){
        $('.not').append(word);
        var value = $(this).data('something');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample without any jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    byId('myFormId').addEventListener('keyup', onFormKeyUp, false);
    byId('myFormId2').addEventListener('keyup', onFormKeyUp, false);
}

// this function was attached to the form in the mInit function.
// as a consequence, 'this' reffers to the form itself.
// this.id should give us the id of the form
function onFormKeyUp(e)
{
    alert("Keyup detected in the form with the id: '" + this.id + "'");
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='myFormId'>
        <input id='textField1'/>
        <br>
        <button>Some button</button>
    </form>
    <form id='myFormId2'>
        <input id='textField2'/>
        <br>
        <button>Some button</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```